# How to prevent a lightweight component receive mouse events?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, listener, event-listener

I have some `JTextComponent`s with some `CaretEvent`s. I need to disable all the components to prevent user interaction after a certain actions and when that actions are completed reenable those `JTextComponent`s to allow the user to interact again with the GUI. Obviously when the user clicks on a `JTextComponent` the caret listener performs it's actions and I want to prevent that.

I currently removed the `CaretListener`s to prevent that and after my internal operations are completed I re-add those `CaretListener`s.

Is there any other way to prevent that? Such removing the `MouseEvent`s for those components and reassign that later?

Comment: *I need to disable all the components to prevent user interaction after a certain actions* - should you maybe be using something like a [Progress Bar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html). This will display a modal dialog preventing user interaction with the form until the progress bar is closed.

Answer (score 1):

One way to disable user interaction is to not allow the text component to receive the program's focus:

```
myTextComponent.setFocusable(false);
```

And then later when you want to re-allow interaction, make the same  call with the obvious `true` parameter:

```
myTextComponent.setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: @user11611653, *Obviously when the user clicks on a JTextComponent the caret listener performs it's actions* - this will still happen, unless the text field contains no text. Removing focus prevents the user from tabbing to the text field. It  does not prevent the user from clicking on the text field and changing the caret position (and generating a CaretEvent).

Comment: @GhostCat: a lesson on how *not* to do customer relations. The initial actions were heavy-handed to say the least, and their initial responses to it, even their initial posts in meta, exceedingly weak